# Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::getAddToCart()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have been struggling in finding a solution for this error. Tried different solutions but getting the same result. The problem is of the second argument and I don't know why it is not working?

Index page:

```
    @extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')
    Laravel Shopping Cart
@endsection

@section('content')
@foreach($products->chunk(3) as $productChunk)
<div class="row">
  @foreach($productChunk as $product)
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="{{$product->imgPath}}" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>{{$product->title}}</h3>
        <p class="description">{{$product->description}} </p>
        <div class="clearfix">
          <div class="price pull-left">${{$product->price}}</div>
            <a href="{{route('product.addToCart', ['id'=>$product->id])}}" class="btn btn-success pull-right" role="button">Add to Cart</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
@endforeach
@endsection
```

ProductController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex(){
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('shop/index',['products' => $products]);
    }

    public function getAddToCart(Request $request, $id){
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        $cart->add($product, $product->id);

        $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
        dd($request->session()->get('cart'));
        return redirect()->route('product.index');
    }
}
```

Route.php

```
    <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'ProductController@getIndex',
    'as' => 'product.index']);

Route::get('add-to-cart', [
    'uses' => 'ProductController@getAddToCart',
    'as' => 'product.addToCart'
    ]);

Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function(){
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function(){

    Route::get('/signup', ['uses' => 'UserController@getSignUp',
    'as' => 'user.signup']);

    Route::post('/signup', ['uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
    'as' => 'user.signup']);

    Route::get('/signin', ['uses' => 'UserController@getSignIn',
    'as' => 'user.signin']);

    Route::post('/signin', ['uses' => 'UserController@postSignIn',
    'as' => 'user.signin']);

    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
        Route::get('/profile', ['uses' => 'UserController@getProfile',
        'as' => 'user.profile']);

        Route::get('/logout', ['uses' => 'UserController@getLogout',
        'as' => 'user.logout']);
    });
});
```

Error Log:

```
ErrorException in ProductController.php line 16:
Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::getAddToCart()
in ProductController.php line 16
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::getAddToCart()', '/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/Http/Controllers/ProductController.php', '16', array('request' => object(Request))) in ProductController.php line 16
at ProductController->getAddToCart(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ProductController), 'getAddToCart'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 80
at Controller->callAction('getAddToCart', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(ProductController), object(Route), 'getAddToCart') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(ProductController), object(Route), object(Request), 'getAddToCart') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductController', 'getAddToCart') in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the id parameter to your defined route

```
Route::get('add-to-cart/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'ProductController@getAddToCart',
    'as' => 'product.addToCart' 
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't send parameter id to controller and action `getAddToCart`.
you should use this code.

`add-to-cart/{id}` and url `add-to-cart/5`

if `id` is optional
use `add-to-cart/{id?}` and url `add-to-cart`